# Laravel Login without auth

Tags: laravel-5

I am very beginner in laravel. I want to create a login registration with my own code without using the laravel auth.

Comment: SO is for asking programming questions, not links.

Comment: If it is a reference link am okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is very possible. There are many authentication packages you can reference and guides to follow for auth in PHP. I highly suggest you implement Laravel's authentication scaffolding and learn how it works in order to build your own. It's really awesome! I provided links to a poplar authentication package you can study through and a tutorial below.

https://github.com/panique/huge

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php